# Compare center pixel with specific number of neighborhood pixels in matlab using nlfilter and set to pixel 1 if condition is met

Tags: matlab, compare, coordinates, nearest-neighbor

I'm try to make a function to slide a 7x7 mask over a matrix (or grayscale image) and compare the center pixel with 36 of the closest neighborhood pixels using nlfilter in matlab.

```
function [ b ] = Slide(A)

b= nlfilter (A,[7 7],@maske);

end

function sammenligne = maske(A)
t=5;
g=18;
center=A(25); %pixel in position 25 is the center pixel of the 7x7 matrix
neigh= A([3:1:5 9:1:13 15:1:24 26:135 37:1:41 45:1:47]); %these are the pixel I want to test. So I want to test pixel in position 3,4,5,15,16 so on in the 7x7 matrix
if abs(neigh-center)<=t
neigh=1;
else
neigh=0;
end

% if (nnz(neigh)>g)
% find position of center pixel 
% else
% 
% end
sammenligne=neigh;
end
```

If the absolute value of the difference between neighborhood pixel and center is less than a set threshold (t). I want to set the tested pixel to 1, else 0.
And if the number of 1 in the matrix is larger than another threshold (g), I want to find the position of the center pixel so I can plot it.

I'm abit stuck if I am on the right way and how I should move forward. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: first, `abs(neigh-center)<=t` is a vector, and thus the if condition will execute only if *all* its values are true. you should probably use `all(abs(neigh-center)<=t)` or `any(abs(neigh-center)<=t)`, depends on what you want.
second, in which matrix you want to count the 1's - in A or in your filtered image? it's not very clear from your question

Comment: Aren't you trying to compare to the 48 closest neighbours rather than 36? Using a 7x7-filter yields 49 values and if you substract the center one, there are 48 left...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user2999345 :)
Didnt know about the all or any function, will try that out. Do I need to use any/all inside the if function to set the selected pixel to 1 (or 0)?
I updated the code in my question, saw I had mixed two codes.
I want to count 1's in the mask. So I can have between 0 and 36 1's. Not sure if I made it more clear.
To answer Max, No I want only to test specific neighbours, so don't want to test all of the 48.

Answer (score 0):

first, use Boolean scalar rather than a vector and return the number of neighbors instead of 1:

```
function N = maske(A)
t=5;
center=A(25); %pixel in position 25 is the center pixel of the 7x7 matrix
neigh= A([3:1:5 9:1:13 15:1:24 26:1:35 37:1:41 45:1:47]); %these are the pixel I want to test. So I want to test pixel in position 3,4,5,15,16 so on in the 7x7 matrix
N = nnz(abs(neigh-center)<=t);
```

for the second thing you want to check just use the previous result:

```
B = nlfilter (A,[7 7],@maske);
b = B > 0;
g = 18;
[yy,xx] = find(B >= g);
```

Comment: I'm getting a error when I try to run it. Error using  >= 
Too many output arguments. 
Error in Slide (line 8)
[yy,xx] = b >= g;

Comment: you're right, i forgot the `find(...)`. now it should be OK

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. But tried it by setting A=magic(7), which makes A a 7x7 matrix. Shouldn't the mask pass over 1 time?  And use it as a input for the main function. With t=2 I get a lot more 1's than I should. Have it missed something?

Comment: you're right again, it should be `find(B >= g)` and not `find(b >= g)`

Comment: about the output size - `nlfilter` pads the input array with zeros before executing so the output will have the same size as the input. you can remove the 3 (in case your filter size is [7 7]) pixels width edges of the input to obtain a "valid" output: `B = B(4:end-3,4:end-3);`

Comment: I haven't been on my computer for some time. Just came back and check your answer. I tried to get the coordinates of the center of A=magic(7), with a threshold t=10 and g=3. With your code I should get N=12. And since N is lager than 3 I should get the coordinates of the cente. Which is A(25) in this case. But it doesn't work like I want it to. I just get empty [ ].

Comment: I tested it on `A = magic(7)` and it gave the expected result... make sure you do `(B >= g)` rather than `(b >= g)`. in order to reconstract the index in the original matrix you can do: `yy = yy + 3;` => `xx = xx + 3;` => `ind = sub2ind(size(A),yy,xx);`